# Flask Form not Posting on Submit

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to modify a bootstrap template's contact form to use a Flask Form I've created. However, when filling out the form and submitting I'm not seeing any POST request on the backend.

I've tried modifying the form such as changing the names of the inputs which seems to be what solved others issues. Double checking the flask form examples and changing the endpoint it's posting to just to see a POST request. Neither have solved the issue.

Flask Code:

```
page = Blueprint('page', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@page.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("FORM POSTED!")
        return "FORM POSTED"
    return render_template("page/index.html", form=form)
```

Flask Form:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextAreaField
from wtforms_components import EmailField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length


class ContactForm(Form):
    email = EmailField('email',
                       [DataRequired(), Length(3, 254)])
    message = TextAreaField('message',
                            [DataRequired(), Length(1, 8192)])
```

HTML Form Template:

```
  <form id="contactForm" name="contactform" method="post" action="{{ url_for('page.home') }}">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ form.email.label }}
                  {{ form.email(class_='form-control', placeholder="Your Email") }}

                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ form.message.label }}
                  {{ form.message(class_='form-control', placeholder="Your Message") }}
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="success"></div>
                <button id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit">Send Message</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

I'm expecting this to require an email and textarea filled out and submitted to the flask app. However nothing is happening. No POST is ever sent.

Comment: Your last `</div>` has no opening tag - does removing this change the outcome?

Comment: Good catch but no luck. Still nothing happening.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the page in-browser to make sure it's rendering properly? Also see if any errors are thrown in the browser's console when you try submitting?

Comment: When you click Submit, what do you see in the Network tab of the Inspector?

Comment: @CameronHyde you got it. Buried in the bootstrap was an example javascript file called "contact_me.js" as soon as I commented it out it started working.  Thanks!